# How do I acknowledge that message has been received in AWS Lamba for a Telegram Bot

Tags: aws-lambda, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a Telegram bot which I run on AWS Lamdba. I use webhooks (not getUpdates) I learnt that if you don't acknowledge that message has received, then Telegram keeps sending it back. So how do I do it?

I am using this library - [Python Telegram Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)

Answer (score 0):

Bot expects response in a very short time period maybe 3 seconds and it does not revieves any response in that time period, bot sends another requests to server or your lambda which causes multiple responses. Since lambda takes time to setup container and some environment so what you can do it that you can add a periodic trigger (CloudWatch Schedule Event) to hit this lambda every 5 or 10 seconds to keep it warm so that it can respond or acknowledge your bot's resquests in short time.